# Networking in windows service

Tags: windows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;


namespace EchoServer
{
    public class SynchronousSocketListener
    {

        // Incoming data from the client.  
        public static string data = null;

        public static void StartListening()
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.  
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
            // Dns.GetHostName returns the name of the
            // host running the application.  
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 31337);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
            Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and
            // listen for incoming connections.  
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);

                // Start listening for connections.  
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.  
                    Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                    String msg = "This is a malicious service, muahahahahahahaha!!!";
                    byte[] encoded_msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
                    handler.Send(encoded_msg);

                    // An incoming connection needs to be processed.  
                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace MaliciousService
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(EchoServer.SynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
            t.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I built this simple service that creates a synchronous socket listener which binds on localhost in port 31337 in a thread. but after I run the service, it seems that the port isn't taken, and the socket calls failed. any ideas why this could happen? (the server was copied from microsoft documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. the lines

```
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 31337);
```

Didn't bind me to loopback. I changed it to

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 31337);
```